# Chrome headless browser with corporate proxy authetication not working

Tags: proxy, selenium-chromedriver, basic-authentication, headless, chrome-options

I am trying to run a Chrome headless browser sitting behind a corporate proxy. I tried below code. But unable to pass through it.

```
public class HeadlessChrome 
{
    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void createChromeDriverHeadless() throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\LocalData\\workspace\\Drivers and Libraries\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");

        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.setHttpProxy("http://user:pwd@server:port");
        proxy.setSslProxy("http://user:pwd@server:port");

//      chromeOptions.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-server=user:pwd@server:port");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");  

        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        driver.get("http://seleniumhq.org");       

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Title : " + driver.getTitle());
        assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("q")).isDisplayed());
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Have you tried `chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-server=http://user:pwd@server:port");` ? `http://` is required

Comment: Yes I have tried but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were not using `headless` you could have used the approach in below link

[user:pass proxies with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330245/userpass-proxies-with-selenium/46331129#46331129)

But with headless extension are currently not allowed. So now your option is add another proxy

```
chrome -> (intermediate proxy w/o auth) -> corporate proxy w/ auth -> internet
```

One options is to use `polipo`

https://www.irif.fr/~jch/software/polipo/

with below config

```
parentAuthCredentials=username:password
parentProxy=corporateproxy:port
```

and then use

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-server=http://polipoproxy:port");
```

The default would be `127.0.0.1:8123` in don't override in polipo config.

Other options you can use

- Use squid proxy instead of polipo
- Write your own proxy forwarder using python or node or any other language you are comfortable with

Answer (score 1):

There is headless browser called Linken-sphere who cooperates with Luminati. They some good offers . you should check them up.
https://miped.ru/f/threads/linken-sphere-antidetekt-brauzer-novogo-pokolenija.67098/

Comment: It is more like a comment then an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to achieve with [selenium 4](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) (currently in beta). You can do it in multiple ways:

1. You basically need to register a check for whether to apply the credentials for any request for authorization. Works for both - basic and proxy auth popups.

   ```
   ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions().setHeadless(true));
   String USER_NAME = "guest";
   String PASSWORD = "guest";
   //register our check here
   driver.register(UsernameAndPassword.of(USER_NAME, PASSWORD));
   driver.get("https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/");
   //Click on the link to show an authentication popup
   driver.findElement(By.linkText("Basic Authentication test")).click();
   String msg = driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).getText();
   assert msg.equalsIgnoreCase("Your browser made it!");
   ```
2. Using [CDP Network domain](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/). Doesn't work for proxy authorization popup (for example here is the similar [issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5077) in puppeteer which goes down to the chrome project)

   ```
   ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions().setHeadless(true));
   String USER_NAME = "guest";
   String PASSWORD = "guest";

   DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
   //create a cdp session
   devTools.createSession();
   //enable network first
   devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));
   //Open website
   driver.get("https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/");
   //Create and send the authorization header
   Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
   String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(String.format("%s:%s", USER_NAME, PASSWORD).getBytes()));
   headers.put("Authorization", basicAuth);
   devTools.send(Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders(new Headers(headers)));
   //Click on the link to show an authentication popup
   driver.findElement(By.linkText("Basic Authentication test")).click();
   String msg = driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).getText();
   assert msg.equalsIgnoreCase("Your browser made it!");
   ```
3. Using the [CDP Fetch domain](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch/). Works for both - basic and proxy auth popups.

   ```
   ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(new ChromeOptions().setHeadless(true));
   String USER_NAME = "guest";
   String PASSWORD = "guest";

   DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();
   //create a cdp session
   devTools.createSession();
   //enable Fetch first
   devTools.send(Fetch.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.of(true)));
   devTools.addListener(Fetch.requestPaused(), requestPaused -> devTools.send(Fetch.continueRequest(requestPaused.getRequestId(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty())));
   devTools.addListener(Fetch.authRequired(), authRequired -> devTools.send(Fetch.continueWithAuth(authRequired.getRequestId(), new AuthChallengeResponse(PROVIDECREDENTIALS, Optional.of(USER_NAME), Optional.of(PASSWORD)))));

   //Open website
   driver.get("https://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/");
   //Click on the link to show an authentication popup
   driver.findElement(By.linkText("Basic Authentication test")).click();
   String msg = driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).getText();
   assert msg.equalsIgnoreCase("Your browser made it!");
   ```