# How to create forwarding proxy-to-proxy with authentication in python

Tags: python, selenium, proxy, http-proxy, seleniumwire

There are plenty of ways to use proxy with selenium and other apps, but most of them don't have proper authenticating method
Chrome\Firefox always asks for login\password and doesn't have built-in ways to provide it as argument, Seleniumwire is a cool thing, but some sites just don't load with it, also requires you to install custom certificate for some sites to work (doesn't help with all of them) using side extensions is not too bad way, but kind of not stable, so

There are things like proxychains, so it is possible to chain proxies even with authentication and without requiring for custom certificates

If you open chrome proxy settings after launching it with seleniumwire, you'll find, it set it to localhost:random port and it uses mitm proxy

What i want to do is to set up similar forwarding proxy, but just as normal proxy, so it just forwards connection to real one and adds authentication, and you can just provide localhost:randomport to --proxy-server argument for browser

browser -> localhost:port -> pythonThread (or any other simple program) -> some http\socks proxy in the wild
browser2 -> localhost:port2 -> pythonThread -> outworld proxy

any existing ways to implement this?
or any ideas\resources i can dig in?
p.s.: i'm using linux, so linux programs are fine as solution

I tried seleniumwire (causes problems with some sites).

I tried ProxyAutoAuth from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46330245/userpass-proxies-with-selenium/46331129) question, but it can't keep long connection to site.

I tried autofilling profiles in stuff like FoxyProxy, but it's not great if you need to switch ip and just kind of bulky, also such extensions usually don't work in headless mode.

I tried proxychains, but it crashes chromium

Comment: Maybe [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles/discussions/6#discussioncomment-4704385) with proxy authentification or [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55582859/20443541) helps you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.